# FreeForm: Adding attributes to the honeypot field

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I'm using VueJS too process and submit forms, and I would like to utilize the freeform honeypot functionality. The issue is that I am unable to add a `v-model` attribute to the honeypot field.

I've already got the CSRF token passing into the VueComponent without issue; I need to get an attribute onto the honeypot field.

Is there a way to do this out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this isn't something that's currently possible. The code that generated the honeypot field isn't able to be extended `vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/src/Services/HoneypotService.php::240`

I ended up doing some js magic, like this:

```
if(this.formHoneypotName) {
    let stickyFingers = form.target.querySelector('#' + this.formHoneypotName)
    params.append(this.formHoneypotName, stickyFingers.value ? stickyFingers.value : '')
}
```